# Check if a number is within 1/1000th of a half digit ( 0, 0.5, 1)

Tags: python

So I'm studying for a programming midterm and one of the subjects is analyzing user inputted numbers.
For example. User enters in X. Program tells if X is within 1/1000th of a half digit ( ...-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1...) and gives you the number that it is closest to.
I.E.
input(1.50001) 1.50001 is close to 1.5
is there a way to do this in a fashion simpler than I am trying to achieve below?

```
N = input("Enter a number: ")
num = float(N)
x = float(N) % 2
print("remainder: ", x)
if x > 1:
    num = float(N) - x
    x = x - 1
if x > float(0.4) and x < float(0.9):
    num = float(N) + x
    x = abs(x - 0.5)
if x < float(1/1000):
    print("Your number: ", x , " is a near half with ", num)
```

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question. I just can't seem to think of a good algorithm for something such as this.

Answer (score 2):

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: "))

# clip err to [-0.25 .. 0.25)
err = ((num + 0.25) % 0.5) - 0.25

if abs(err) < 0.001:
    print("{} is within 0.001 of {}".format(num, num - err))
```

which runs like

```
Enter a number: 1.50003
1.50003 is within 0.001 of 1.5
```

Comment: Never realized you could do `a % b` for non-integer b

Comment: Oh wow that is soooo much simpler. I knew I was overthinking this and would be a way to accomplish it with fewer lines. Thanks!!